# Amazon EFS Logging

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-efs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have two EFS entities. I have created a log group inside CloudWatch but still empty (no stream). How do I relay all EFS logs into the log group? The ultimate goal is to monitor the logs especially when throughput % goes high.

I have tried the following command but failed:

```
aws efs update-file-system --file-system-id <ID> --logging-configuration '{"FileAccessLogDestination": <log group ID>, "FileAccessLogDestinationType":"CloudWatchLogs", "FileAccessLogFormat":"TEXT"}'
```

```
aws efs update-file-system --file-system-id <ID> --logging-configuration '{"FileAccessLogDestination": <log group ID>, "FileAccessLogDestinationType":"CloudWatchLogs", "FileAccessLogFormat":"TEXT"}'
```

Comment: I looked at both the V1 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/efs/update-file-system.html and V2 https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/efs/update-file-system.html versions of the AWS CLI tool documentation, and I don't see anything like a `--logging-configuration` option in the documentation. Further, I have never heard or any such logging feature for AWS EFS (Elastic File System). Are you sure EFS is the correct service for whatever you are trying to do?

Comment: Well neither did I! How can I do it through the console rather than using CLI?

Comment: How can you do *what*? My comment was for clarification on exactly what you are trying to do. You appear to be trying to do something that is not supported at all by the EFS service and it is entirely unclear what you are attempting.